# How to set up drilldown feature for multiple boxplot series in highcharter?

Tags: r, highcharts, data-visualization, r-highcharter

#### Solution Below

*Original Question:*
I'm attempting to create a drilldown plot in highcharter that uses boxplots.
The goal here is to start with boxplots on a monthly timescale. The process is as follows:

1. Initial view - Boxplot with months as x-axis
2. Clicking on a specific month drills down into a new series of boxplots where the x-axis is the weeks that make up the month selected
3. Lastly, clicking on a week within the month selected then drills down into a new series of boxplots where the x-axis is the days that are specific to that week.

A couple things to note, I've modified the `data_to_boxplot` function in two ways. First by adding the ability to show no. of observations in `get_box_values`. Second, I've added a drilldown field in `data_to_boxplot` that corresponds to the name of the series. Which is used in `hc_drilldown`

### The Code:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)
library(highcharter)
library(data.table)

# Helper functions
group_by_timescale = function(x,unit="day") {
  if (unit=="month") {
    lubridate::rollback(x, roll_to_first = TRUE)
  } else if (unit=="week") {
    floor_date(x, "week", week_start = 1)+6
  } else if (unit=="day") {
    x
  }
}
get_box_values <- function(x) {
  boxplot.stats(x)$stats %>% 
    t() %>% 
    cbind(boxplot.stats(x)$n) %>% 
    as.data.frame() %>%
    setNames(c("low", "q1", "median", "q3", "high", "obs"))
}
get_outliers_values <- function(x) {
  boxplot.stats(x)$out
}

# Modified highcharter function
data_to_boxplot_2 = function (data, variable, group_var = NULL, group_var2 = NULL, add_outliers = FALSE, ...) {
  stopifnot(is.data.frame(data), !missing(variable))
  # browser()
  dx <- data %>% 
    transmute(`:=`(x, {
      {
        variable
      }
    }))
  if (!missing(group_var)) {
    dg <- data %>% select({
      {
        group_var
      }
    })
  }
  else {
    dg <- data.frame(rep(0, nrow(dx)))
  }
  if (!missing(group_var2)) {
    dg2 <- data %>% select({
      {
        group_var2
      }
    })
  }
  else {
    dg2 <- data.frame(rep(NA, nrow(dx)))
  }
  dg <- dg %>% setNames("name")
  dg2 <- dg2 %>% setNames("series")
  dat <- bind_cols(dx, dg, dg2)
  dat1 <- dat %>% 
    group_by(series, name) %>% 
    summarise(data = list(get_box_values(x)),.groups = "drop") %>% 
    unnest(cols = data) %>%
    mutate(drilldown = name) %>% # add drilldown name to series
    group_nest(series) %>% 
    mutate(data = map(data, list_parse)) %>% 
    rename(name = series) %>% 
    mutate(id = name) %>% 
    mutate(type = "boxplot", ...)
  
  if (add_outliers) {
    dat2 <- dat %>% 
      mutate(name = as.numeric(factor(name)) - 1) %>% 
      group_by(series, name) %>% 
      summarise(y = list(get_outliers_values(x)),.groups = "drop") %>% 
      unnest(cols = y) %>% 
      rename(x = name) %>% 
      group_nest(series) %>% 
      mutate(data = map(data, list_parse)) %>% 
      rename(linkedTo = series) %>% 
      mutate(type = "scatter", showInLegend = FALSE, ...)
    
    dout <- bind_rows(dat1, dat2)
  }
  else {
    dout <- dat1
  }
  dout
}

# Sample data
dates = sort(rep(seq.Date(from = as_date("2021-01-01"), to = as_date("2021-12-31"), by = "day"),15))
data = data.table(
  day = dates,
  values = floor(runif(length(dates), 0, 1000))
)

data[, `:=` (
  weeks = group_by_timescale(day, "week"),
  months = group_by_timescale(day, "month")
)]

# Create Boxplot series
month_dt = data_to_boxplot_2(data, variable = values, group_var = months, name = "month")
week_dt = data_to_boxplot_2(data, variable = values, group_var = weeks, group_var2 = months, name = "week")
day_dt = data_to_boxplot_2(data, variable = values, group_var = day, group_var2 = weeks, name = "day")

# Drilldown HC plot
hc <- highchart() %>%
  hc_title(text = "Basic drilldown") %>%
  hc_xAxis(type = "category") %>%
  hc_legend(enabled = FALSE) %>%
  hc_plotOptions(series = list(borderWidth = 0,dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE))) %>%
  hc_add_series_list(month_dt) %>%
  hc_drilldown(allowPointDrilldown = TRUE,
               series = list(week_dt, day_dt))
```

Below is an image of the plot output. The x-axis values, when clicked, should result in a new boxplot but nothing happens. I'm suspect that it has to do with how my data is grouped but not sure. Any help on this would be great! Thanks
[image: drill down plot]

### EDIT: Solution

I'm still a bit new to R so my explanation may unintentionally omit details. After tinkering around, I've discovered that `hc_drilldown(series)` expects an array of series configurations that are in the highcharts series option. When using the `data_to_boxplot` function the output is a tibble with a nested list. So in order to add the drill down series to hc_drilldown. The tibble needs to be parsed to a list. Using `highcharter::list_parse2` removes all names and I need to keep the name values in the series like "name", "id" etc.

I created a function to output a hc drilldown box plot for n number of drilldown series. In my example I ended up using `rlist::list.parse(series) %>% setNames(NULL)` since that only removes the top level names in the list, but pretty sure `highcharter::list_parse` will work as well now that I think about it (thanks @Kat). Then, all I needed to do was append the lists using `c()` in hc_drilldown. One thing to note, the values in the drilldown columns used need to be unique i.e. have unique "ids" otherwise it's possible that clicking on the first series drilldown can bypass the middle levels and go directly to the most granular series. In my example below, clicking on Monthly "2021-08-01" will bypass the weeks in August and go to the day drilldown series.

#### New Working Code

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)
library(highcharter)
library(data.table)

# Helper functions
group_by_timescale = function(x,unit="day") {
  if (unit=="month") {
    lubridate::rollback(x, roll_to_first = TRUE)
  } else if (unit=="week") {
    floor_date(x, "week", week_start = 1)+6
  } else if (unit=="day") {
    x
  }
}
get_box_values <- function(x) {
  boxplot.stats(x)$stats %>% 
    t() %>% 
    cbind(boxplot.stats(x)$n) %>% 
    as.data.frame() %>%
    setNames(c("low", "q1", "median", "q3", "high", "obs"))
}
get_outliers_values <- function(x) {
  boxplot.stats(x)$out
}

# Modified HC function
data_to_boxplot_2 = function (data, variable, group_var = NULL, group_var2 = NULL, 
drilldown = FALSE, add_outliers = FALSE, ...) {
  stopifnot(is.data.frame(data), !missing(variable))
  # browser()
  dx <- data %>% 
    transmute(`:=`(x, {
      {
        variable
      }
    }))
  if (!missing(group_var)) {
    dg <- data %>% select({
      {
        group_var
      }
    })
  }
  else {
    dg <- data.frame(rep(0, nrow(dx)))
  }
  if (!missing(group_var2)) {
    dg2 <- data %>% select({
      {
        group_var2
      }
    })
  }
  else {
    dg2 <- data.frame(rep(NA, nrow(dx)))
  }
  dg <- dg %>% setNames("name")
  dg2 <- dg2 %>% setNames("series")
  dat <- bind_cols(dx, dg, dg2)
  dat1 <- dat %>% 
    group_by(series, name) %>% 
    summarise(data = list(get_box_values(x)),.groups = "drop") %>% 
    unnest(cols = data)
  
  if(drilldown) {
    dat1 <- dat1 %>%
      mutate(drilldown = name)
  }
  
  dat1 <- dat1 %>%
    group_nest(series) %>% 
    mutate(data = map(data, list_parse)) %>% 
    rename(name = series) %>% 
    mutate(id = name) %>% 
    mutate(type = "boxplot", ...)
  
  if (add_outliers) {
    dat2 <- dat %>% 
      mutate(name = as.numeric(factor(name)) - 1) %>% 
      group_by(series, name) %>% 
      summarise(y = list(get_outliers_values(x)),.groups = "drop") %>% 
      unnest(cols = y) %>% 
      rename(x = name) %>% 
      group_nest(series) %>% 
      mutate(data = map(data, list_parse)) %>% 
      rename(linkedTo = series) %>% 
      mutate(type = "scatter", showInLegend = FALSE, ...)
    
    dout <- bind_rows(dat1, dat2)
  }
  else {
    dout <- dat1
  }
  dout
}

# Sample data
dates = sort(rep(seq.Date(from = as_date("2021-01-01"), to = as_date("2021-12-31"), by = "day"),15))
data = data.table(
  day = dates,
  values = floor(runif(length(dates), 0, 1000))
)

data[, `:=` (
  weeks = group_by_timescale(day, "week"),
  months = group_by_timescale(day, "month")
)]

# vector indicating the relationship between each drilldown series
# the first position is the top level
groups = c("months", "weeks", "day")

# create hc drilldown boxplot
drilldown_boxplot = function(dt, var, dd_groups, parent_name = "Monthly") {
  dd_size = length(dd_groups)
  all_dd = list()
  
  # create boxplot series lists
  for (idx in 1:dd_size) {
    if (idx == 1) {
      all_dd[[idx]] = data_to_boxplot_2(dt, variable = get(var), group_var = dd_groups[idx], 
                                         drilldown = TRUE, name = parent_name)
    } else if (idx == length(dd_groups)) {
      all_dd[[idx]] = data_to_boxplot_2(dt, variable = get(var), group_var = dd_groups[idx], 
                                         group_var2 = dd_groups[idx-1])
    } else {
      all_dd[[idx]] = data_to_boxplot_2(dt, variable = get(var), group_var = dd_groups[idx], 
                                         group_var2 = dd_groups[idx-1], drilldown = TRUE)
    }
  }
  
  parent_series = all_dd[[1]]
  child_series = tail(all_dd, dd_size-1)
  child_series_exp = c()
  
  # parse lists to be readable in hc_drilldown
  for (i in 1:length(child_series)) {
    s = rlist::list.parse(child_series[[i]]) %>% setNames(NULL)
    child_series_exp = c(child_series_exp, s)
  }
  
  # create hc drilldown boxplot
  hc = highchart() %>%
    hc_xAxis(type = "category") %>%
    hc_legend(enabled = FALSE) %>%
    hc_plotOptions(series = list(borderWidth = 0, dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE))) %>%
    hc_add_series_list(parent_series) %>%
    hc_drilldown(allowPointDrilldown = TRUE,
                 series = child_series_exp)
  
  return(hc)
}

drilldown_boxplot(data, "values", groups)
```

Comment: It looks like you're fairly new to SO; welcome to the community! If you want great answers quickly, it's best to make your question reproducible. This includes sample data like the output from `dput(head(dataObject)))`. And like you mentioned, it is definitely possible that the data structure is the issue. [Read about writing a great question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269).

Comment: Hi, @Kat thanks for the tips, I'll read through that article. In this case however, I did provide sample data and the code above is reproducible. Is there something else I should be including for you/others?

Answer (score 1):

I just missed that the data was present, sorry about that. You did provide a lot of content.

I am able to get your first drill-down to weeks, but another level to days. I actually haven't been able to find any examples of that level either. I find that to be odd. I know that my days of working with PowerBI had multiple-level drill-downs. If it's possible in HC, I haven't figured it out.

You only need to modify your call to `hc_drilldown`.

```
hc_drilldown(allowPointDrilldown = TRUE,
             series = list_parse(week_dt))
```

The entire call to create `hc`:

```
# Drilldown HC plot
(hc <- highchart() %>%
  hc_title(text = "Basic drilldown") %>%
  hc_xAxis(type = "category") %>%
  hc_legend(enabled = FALSE) %>%
  hc_plotOptions(series = list(borderWidth = 0,
                               dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE))) %>%
  hc_add_series_list(month_dt) %>%
  hc_drilldown(allowPointDrilldown = TRUE,
               series = list_parse(week_dt))
```

[image]

I feel like there has to be a way to add another drill-down level. If I figure it out, I will edit my answer.

---

*Updated*

---

Based on the comments had back and forth, this is how I changed the attributes: drill-downs, ids, and names to try to get `highcharter` to recognize the third-level depth. This won't necessarily work as it is, because I think the structure of the data changed in your updated question (solution?). Gah, you know what I mean.

Before the object `week_dt` was created, I added `data[, "weeks" := lubridate::week(weeks)]` to change the id's of the nested weeks' content to be the week number.

After the `months_dt`, `weeks_dt`, and `day_dt` were created I changed the attributes.

In `months_dt` I changed the attribute `drilldown` to the month label. When m2 is created, it's just a list of months, that I use afterwards. I used the `<<-` within the code to change `months_dt`.

```
m2 <- lapply(1:length(month_dt$data[[1]]), 
             function(x){
               val <- month_dt$data[[1]][[x]][[8]]
               month_dt$data[[1]][[x]][[8]] <<- lubridate::month(val, 
                                                                 label = T) %>% 
                 as.character()
             })
```

Then used `m2` to make the attribute `drilldown` in `months_dt` match the `name` and `id` of each week group that's attached to a specific month group (not the nested weeks' data).

```
week_dt$id <- unlist(m2)
week_dt$name <- unlist(m2)
```

I changed the grouping names of the object `days_dt` to match the `drilldown` within the weeks, which is 1:52 weeks in a year. Since the `id` already carries this information, I used it.

```
day_dt$name <- day_dt$id
```

Then when that still didn't create a relationship that would generate the third-level drill-down (which you have working now), I removed the `drilldown` attribute from day_dt.

```
lapply(1:length(day_dt$data),
       function(x) {
         lapply(1:length(day_dt$data[[x]]),
                function(y){
                  day_dt$data[[x]][[y]][8] <<- NULL
                })
       })
```

This didn't actually work as I had hoped, so I didn't include it originally. Perhaps the week numbers needed to be character fields, between `drilldown` and `name`/`id`? It didn't seem likely since both date-type and character-type worked for the between months and weeks.

Comment: Really appreciate you looking into this and I've +1 your answer. I initially used `list_parse2` when testing which didn't work and ended up using `rlist::list.parse() %>% setNames (NULL)`. Looks like `list_parse` would work since it's essentially doing the same thing. I've updated my question with my solution for getting it to work. Please let me know if I'm missing something.

Comment: Looks great to me! I couldn't find the package `raUtilities`, though. (Not through Cran or Github... I'm sure it's somewhere...)

Comment: @Jamie I actually went through all of the code to change the ids, drill-down labels, and names when I was trying to get the third level to work. I ended up setting the drill-down labels for the month series to the month name, then named the week series sets the month name (to match the drill-down label). I changed the week's to the week number, to get around the problem with the date-id name match issue. I could add that code if you wanted it. Just let me know. (That was overly wordy...but not sure how to say that better!)

Comment: Whoops didn't mean to include that, that package is private. And if you don't mind, I'm interested to see how you did that. I've got it working for me by formatting the timescale columns differently but wanted to add that note incase anyone else gave this a try.